# Rails 4: sorting items in chronological order in nested loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 app, I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :first_name, to: :user, prefix: true
end
```

In my `Calendar#Index` view, I needed to display a list of all the comments (from all posts and all calendars) of a user.

So, I updated my `Calendar#Index` controller as follows:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @calendars = @user.calendars.all
end
```

And, in my `Calendar#Index` view, I wrote the following code:

```
<table id="my_todo_table">

  <% @calendars.each do |calendar| %>

    <% calendar.comments.each do |comment| %>

      <tr>

        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= link_to calendar.name, calendar_path(calendar.id) %></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= comment.post.subject %> </td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= comment.user.first_name %></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= comment.body %></td>

      </tr>

    <% end %>

  <% end %>

</table>
```

This is working well, except for one small detail: currently, comments are sorted by calendars, and then by post (which makes sense, given the code above).

Instead, I would like to have them sorted in chronological order, ie the most recent first first, **regardless of which calendar or post it belongs to**.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could order by `created_at` datetime like so:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @calendars = Comment.where("user_id like ?", @user.id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This will order my comments? Or my calendars?

Comment: This will order your calendars. Is that what you are looking for? You will need to order something whether based on the calendars, post, or comments

Comment: No, I am not looking to order the calendars. I am looking to order the comments.

Comment: I understand what you write on the right side of the equal sign, but I feel like we should not store `Comments` in a `@calendars`.

Comment: Si tu veux ordonner des commentaires de tes utilisateur ma réponse et correct. Peu être changer le nom de variable d'instance serai mieux

Comment: Thanks. Happy to speak with a French speaker on SO. If I understand correctly, your answer lets a user display a list of his own comments. This is not what I want. I want to display all the comments, related to all the posts, from all the calendars that belong to a user. And the cherry on the cake would be to allow this user not to see his own comments listed.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do a new ActiveRecord query for the comments, since you are getting the comments through calendars, I would do something like this.

```
@comments = Comment.joins(post: :calendar).where(calendars: {id: @calendars.pluck(:id)}).distinct.order(created_at: :desc)
```

This will find all the comments that belong to a calendar and order the comments according to the created_at time stamp